# Why and When to use JSON

Tags: ajax, json, rest, web, service

I know what JSON is and what the advantages over XML. I already read some answer for this , but still i can't get through it.

So i would specifically ask this questions: 
1. Is it only useful for API thing? so exchange data without refresh the whole page using AJAX.. 
2. Is it always used with AJAX? 
3. Do people (always/very often) using JSON like this? :: Database/Server - JSON - Client.. what i mean by that is, all our data from database will be put into JSON, so people can use it easily to any other platform/language?

**because from my point of view, if the data, which we need to output not much, why not just directly write on HTML directly, and if it's a lot of data, why not use database? If you don't mind please add an example case to use json

big thanks everyone!

Comment: 1. why, no, you can use it for whatever you want… 2. obviously no, 3. often, but as I mentioned, JSON does not have to be used in this context exclusively.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! can you give me a real example? because from my point of view, if the data, which we need to output not much, why not just static write on HTML directly, and if it much data, why not use database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JSON is a lightweight data interchange format, it's uses vary widely. You describe using it for an API, which would be an idea situation to use JSON output over something like XML.

To specifically answer your questions:

1. It's not just useful for an API. It can be used to create configuration (for example, [Composer](http://www.getcomposer.org)'s JSON configuration file). It can also be used for basic output to easily read with languages like JavaScript, since JSON is native to JavaScript as an object. (**J**avaScript **O**bject **N**otation).
2. It's not always used for AJAX. Say you were building a PHP application to convert currency, and you wanted to read from an API that output as JSON, this would always be preferred. Because languages like PHP have the ability to encode and decode JSON, you could read from the API (or other source) and decode it, giving you a PHP object or array of the JSON data.
3. I think you mean reading from a database, outputting that in JSON format and then allowing clients to read it using an API. In this case, it's not always the way it's used - but if I had to guess, it's the most common way it's used, and probably most useful.

Answer (score 0):

the JSON in my opinion, when you get  some data from netWork , you can use the JSON  to describe your data . JSON only is a data format. it isn't always used with AJAX . it's only a format. It contains array and dictionary.